# How to check all of items in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want develop test application and for this I want use this API : https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52772

In this API for show some info use many field, such as `strIngredient1`, `strIngredient2`, `strIngredient3` and more to `strIngredient15`.

I want first check each of this items, and when not empty. then show this.
There are 15 items and I don't want check each of items!
I want check all of this items and each item not empty then show it!

How can I it? Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the response, in some case response may be like this due to bad code from backend developer and things will not be in our control.

We can do some hack to sort out your problem. Check out this code snippet:

```
val meals = response.getJSONArray("meals")
    val meal = meals.getJSONObject(0)
    for(i in 1..20){
        val gradient = meal.getString("strIngredient${i}")
        if(!gradient.isNullOrBlank()){
            println(gradient)
            //Do whatever you want
        }
    }
```

I have just created a loop and the concat index with hard-coded string that will make a required attribute name and you can get the data from that json object.